# Does Mongoose support the Mongodb `findAndModify` method?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I would like to use findAndModify to atomically increment a field, using Mongoose.

However, the code below throws the error "TypeError: Object # has no method 'findAndModify'":

```
// defining schema for the "counters" table
var tableSchema = new Schema({
    _id: String,
    next: Number        
});

// creating table object for the counters table
var counters_table = mongoose.model('counters', tableSchema);
var tableObj = new counters_table();    

// increment the "next" field on the table object
var query = {_id: 'messagetransaction'};
var update = {'$inc': {next: 1}};
var ret = tableObj.findAndModify(query, [], update, true, true, function(err) {
     if (err) { 
         throw err;
     }
     else { 
         console.log("updated!");
     }
});
```

Comment: As per the mongodb documentation the findAndModify should be as follows,

Collection.prototype.findAndModify = function(query, sort, update,new_doc, remove_doc, function(err) {
//})

But not working when convert this into mongoose type! Please clarify me on this!

Comment: Mongoose v3 docs: [findOneAndUpdate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate) or [findOneAndRemove](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndRemove)

Answer (score 62):

The feature is not well (read: at all) documented, but after reading through the source code, I came up with the following solution.

**Create your collection schema.**

```
var Counters = new Schema({
  _id: String,
  next: Number     
});
```

**Create a static method on the schema which will expose the findAndModify method of the model's collection.**

```
Counters.statics.findAndModify = function (query, sort, doc, options, callback) {
  return this.collection.findAndModify(query, sort, doc, options, callback);
};
```

**Create your model.**

```
var Counter = mongoose.model('counters', Counters);
```

**Find and modify!**

```
Counter.findAndModify({ _id: 'messagetransaction' }, [], { $inc: { next: 1 } }, {}, function (err, counter) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('updated, counter is ' + counter.next);
});
```

**Bonus**

```
Counters.statics.increment = function (counter, callback) {
  return this.collection.findAndModify({ _id: counter }, [], { $inc: { next: 1 } }, callback);
};

Counter.increment('messagetransaction', callback);
```

Comment: and of course, you could add an increment method on the instance

Comment: how to get the return value of findAndModify via this method?

Comment: I'd suppose, like with everywhere else — by reading it from the second parameter inside your callback.

Comment: I got return = undefined

Answer (score 21):

This is fully supported in Mongoose 3.x now, though the name is slightly different.

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndRemove

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndRemove

Comment: These only allow for the finding of single entries

Comment: MongoDB has the same limitation (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/).

Comment: these are all deprecated now.

Comment: @chovy none of them are deprecated in the current version (5.11.19)

Answer (score 14):

Made working version increment for Mongoose 3.x

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var CounterSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: String,
    next: {type: Number, default: 1}
});

CounterSchema.statics.increment = function (counter, callback) {
    return this.findByIdAndUpdate(counter, { $inc: { next: 1 } }, {new: true, upsert: true, select: {next: 1}}, callback);
};
```

Use something like this:

```
Counter.increment('photo', function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.error('Counter on photo save error: ' + err); return;
    }
    photo.cid = result.next;
    photo.save();
});
```

I hope someone come in handy

Comment: It came in handy, indeed, but FWIW I eventually came up with Redis-based counters. Much faster and much easier.

Answer (score 7):

In version 3, the mongoose findOneAndUpdate method exposes mongodb's findAndModify operation. It works like so:

```
var query = { name: 'Sprinkls' };
var update = { name: 'Sprinkles' };
var options = { new: false };
Cat.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options, function (err, cat) {
  if (err) ..
  render('cat', cat);
});
```

More info here: http://aaronheckmann.tumblr.com/post/48943524629/mongoose-v3-part-2-findandmodify

Answer (score 4):

a lot of answers but I find this simple solution.

```
Counter.findByIdAndUpdate(ID, {$inc: {next:1}}, function (err, data) {


});
```

Answer (score 3):

I got findAndModify to

- Upsert a counter (create and initialize it if it doesn't exist)
- Increment the counter
- Call a callback with the incremented value

in a single DB roundtrip using the following code:

```
var Counters = new Schema({
  _id:String, // the schema name
  count: Number
});

Counters.statics.findAndModify = function (query, sort, doc, options, callback) {
    return this.collection.findAndModify(query, sort, doc, options, callback);
};

var Counter = mongoose.model('Counter', Counters);

/**
 * Increments the counter associated with the given schema name.
 * @param {string} schemaName The name of the schema for which to
 *   increment the associated counter.
 * @param {function(err, count)} The callback called with the updated
 *   count (a Number).
 */
function incrementCounter(schemaName, callback){
  Counter.findAndModify({ _id: schemaName }, [], 
    { $inc: { count: 1 } }, {"new":true, upsert:true}, function (err, result) {
      if (err)
        callback(err);
      else
        callback(null, result.count);
  });
}
```

Enjoy!
- Curran

Answer (score 2):

Taking the above response from [@furf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7592756/4025963), this is my `promised` solution:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line func-names
localeTypesSchema.statics.findAndModify = function (query, sort, update, opts, callback) {
    const cb = callback || (() => { });
    try {
        const result = this.collection.findAndModify(query || {}, sort || [], update || {}, opts);
        cb(null, result);
        return Promise.resolve(result);
    } catch (err) {
        cb(err);
        return Promise.reject(err);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the direct command style shown at the bottom of http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/findAndModify+Command. I'm not familiar enough with mongoose to know the method for running a command, but all drivers provide some way to do it. If mongoose doesn't, you can do it directly using the style described at the top of http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Commands.

That said, you should make sure that you really need `findAndModify` and that `update` won't do what you need it to do. To see what `update` is capable of take a look at http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating.

Answer (score 0):

just adding to furf answer that if you use objectId in your query, mongoDB will not be able to find your document. The mongoose layer takes care of converting the Hex string object id you get from the routing params to the proper object id.

to solve this you need to:

```
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;


var itemId = req.params.itemId;
var objectId = ObjectID.createFromHexString(itemId);
Item.findAndModify({_id: objectId},
```