# Mongoose findByIdAndUpdate() or update() and increment(). How to increment __v?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Is there the way to combine `Model.findByIdAndUpdate` and `Model.increment()` which increments mongoose native versionKey? Or `Model.update()` and any incrementation of `__v`?

This code doesn't increment `__v`

```js
Station.update({ _id: req.params.id }, 
               { $set: req.body, $inc: { __v: 1 } }, 
               { multi: false },  callback);
```

but increments any custom `Number` field:

```js
Station.update({ _id: req.params.id }, 
               { $set: req.body, $inc: { count: 1 } }, 
               { multi: false },  callback);
```

So far I've found only one way to increment `__v`:

```js
Station.findById(req.params.id, function (err, station) {
    station.increment();  // this increments __v
    station.save(req.body, callback)
})
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334390/has-mongoose-support-findandmodify-mongodb-method

Answer (score 4):

[It's possible that this is by design.](http://aaronheckmann.posterous.com/mongoose-v3-part-1-versioning)  In particular `__v` is a special mongoose internal key whose specific use is to prevent multiple save operations from colliding when an Array element of the document has positional changes.  Atomic update operations by themselves aren't exposed to this risk, so in isolation they don't need to increment `__v`.

However it is possible to interleave atomic updates with the non atomic find/save constructs, so I submitted an [issue](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/1265) for the developer to look at.