# mongodb/mongoose findAndModify setoninsert

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Im trying to find the user in the stats, and if they dont exist, create them and give me the info.

Starting is executed, but i dont get any response on the other console.logs, or response.

How can i fix this to work?

```
console.log("starting");
var playerid = "57c435669f437e007b974fbb";

Crimestats.findAndModify({ query: { userid : playerid}, update: { $setOnInsert: { userid : playerid }}}).then( function(err, stats){
             if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }

            console.log("got any results");
            console.log(stats);

            resolve(stats);

        });
```

Only response is:

```
starting
```

Comment: Use `.catch()` or second argument of `.then` to check what the error was.

Comment: See if [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334390/has-mongoose-support-findandmodify-mongodb-method) can help you.

Comment: i couldnt find that to work.

Comment: I think there is some syntax error. So that it is not going inside `.then()`. Since I have no idea about mogoose, I can't point you out the place you need to change.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add option for insert new one if not exist so need to add `upsert: true`

Can try it:

```
var playerid = "57c435669f437e007b974fbb";

Crimestats.findAndModify({
  query:{ userid : playerid},
  update: {
    $set: { name: "xxx" }, // if found update name or when insert
    $setOnInsert: { userid : playerid }
  },
  upsert: true
 }
).then( function(err, stats){
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  console.log("got any results");
  console.log(stats);

  resolve(stats);
});
```