# How to make a parallel and sequential job queue (FIFO) from MongoDB collection?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Here is my schema of the collection:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var urlSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  url:  String,
  easeDate: { type: Date, index: 1},
  created: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});
```

I need to do an update action with the oldest document (by easeDate) to change its `easeDate` date to «now + some timeout» and get the affected document. Is it possible in one request?

Basically, I want to make something like a queue from the collection (the "oldest" one is the next one pulled out i.e. first in first out). Deletion of urls (documents in the collection) is done by other conditions. I don't want to delete from queue but put to the end of it by updating `easeDate`.

Finally, I want to take the available url and set a timeout to it, so that the next time there was returned the next url. If it was the last url, then `null` is returned next time, because of timeout.

And if I can update it so, how can I query the database (mongoose) to get the next url where easeDate < Date.now()? Could you please give an example in JavaScript?

Comment: Duplicate reference is wrong! I updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

## Use findAndModify() with sort

If you're accessing your stack **from a single machine** you can do so using **findAndRemove**:

```
Model.collection.findAndModify({query:{}, sort:{created: 1}, remove:true})
```

You need to access `collection` because `mongoose` doesn't implements

`findAndModify`, *you have `findOneAndUpdate` but it doesn't delete documents*

More information:

[Does Mongoose support the Mongodb `findAndModify` method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334390/does-mongoose-support-the-mongodb-findandmodify-method)

Comment: Sorting is actually supported by the [`.findOneAndRemove()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndRemove) mongoose method as well. So you don't really need to dig into the underlying driver.

Comment: I guess,`.findOneAndUpdate()` is the best in my situation (I updated the question). What about querying the next available document in the queue?